# Differentiate ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> duplicate objects

Tags: java, android

My app deals with itineraries and distances between cities. Because some itineraries match with more than one city, an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` is creating with duplicate items-itineraries. Few lines below i need to assign distances to that duplicate itineraries. Here comes the problem...I can't assign different distances to that duplicate objects.

I thought that different position differentiates those duplicate items...Is there any way to differentiate them; I tried with `ArrayList<Hashmap<String>>` with no results.

Comment: Use a class to store the data instead of a `List<String>`, then make the IDE implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for you. And use a `Set` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there if you are able to get google guava library you could create a generic static function below, bonus is guava library is small and many features that are useful regarding lists and collections.

```
//Static method
private static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(final List<T> list) {
      return Lists.newArrayList(ImmutableSet.copyOf(newArrayList<Object()).asList());
 }

//Call like this
removeDuplicates("YOUR LIST GOES HERE")
```